# Очистка формы jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

Есть две формы на сайте.
Там же и кнопка очистить. 
При нажатии очищает содержимое инпутов.

```
$document.on('click', '.js-clearApplication', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('.js-form');
    form.find('input, textarea').val('');
});
```

Одна из  форм в модалке, которая по умолчанию имеет `display: none`

Тут то очистка и не работает. 
Я так понимаю, из-за того что при загрузке страницы это формы нету в DOM

Как решить проблему?

Пример разметки

```
<form class="header__application-form js-applicationForm js-form" action="">
                        <div>
                            <p>Ваше имя</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя">
                            <p>Телефон</p>
                            <input type="tel" placeholder="+7 ____ ____ __ __">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Комментарий</p>
                            <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Пожалуйста, опишите подробнее
о своём празднике."></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Почта</p>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="@inbox.ru">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="Btn_black">Отправить</button>
                            <!--<button class="reset" type="reset">Стереть</button>-->
                            <a class="js-clearApplication" href="#">Стереть</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Попробовал добавить button[type=reset]
Что то оно не чистит форму( 
Основная проблема в том,  что  клик по кнопке не обрабатывается.

Т.е оно не доходит до того, что бы чистить форму

Comment: У `jquery` есть метод `trigger` им и отчистите -  `form.trigger('reset');`

Answer (score -1):

Можно просто использовать стандартную кнопку очистки формы `<input type="reset" />`

```html
<form>
<h2>Форма №1</h2>
<input type="text" />
<input type="reset" />
</form>

<form>
<h2>Форма №2</h2>
<input type="text" />
<input type="reset" />
</form>
```

Слой со стилем `display: none` присутствует в разметке при загрузке страницы просто он не отображается. Если нужно именно очистить форму с помощью скрипта то попробуйте:

```js
$(function() {
 $('.js-clearApplication').click(function(){
  $('.js_input').val('');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <h2>Форма №1</h2>
    <input type="text" class="js_input" />
    <input type="button" value="Очистить" class="js-clearApplication" />
    </form>

    <form>
    <h2>Форма №2</h2>
    <input type="text" class="js_input" />
    <input type="button"  value="Очистить" class="js-clearApplication" />
    </form>
```

Comment: У меня изначально клик на копку не работает. 
При клике консл лог мочит даже.
Тук у меня форма имеет класс .js-form
А оттуда уже берет инпуты и очищает их.

Comment: Ну вы пример разметки не показали. Лучше всего использовать `<input type="reset" />`

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том,  что клик по кнопке просто не происходит.
Оно не видит её.